# PHP email with attachment limiting file type and size

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with adding file type and size limits to my php email code. I've tried adding numerous snippets I've found online which relate to uploading but no success. Any help is greatly appreciated.

php:

```
<?php

$to = $_POST['toEmail'];
$fromEmail = $_POST['fieldFormEmail']; 
$fromName = $_POST['fieldFormName']; 
$subject = $_POST['fieldSubject']; 
$message = $_POST['fieldDescription'];

/* GET File Variables */ 
$tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
$fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 

/* Start of headers */ 
$headers = "From: $fromName"; 

if (file($tmpName)) { 
  /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
  $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
  fclose($file); 

  /* a boundary string */
  $randomVal = md5(time()); 
  $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x"; 

  /* Header for File Attachment */
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
  $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 

  /* Multipart Boundary above message */
  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
  $message . "\n\n"; 

  /* Encoding file data */
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

  /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
  $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" . 
  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
  $data . "\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n"; 
} 

$flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers"); 

if($flgchk){
  echo "A email has been sent to: $to";
 }
else{
  echo "Error in Email sending";
}
?>
```

html:

```
<form action="emailSend.php" method="post" name="mainform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
       <tr>
        <th>Your Name</th>
        <td><input name="fieldFormName" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Your Email</th>
        <td><input name="fieldFormEmail" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>To Email</th>
        <td><input name="toEmail" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <td><input name="fieldSubject" type="text" id="fieldSubject"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <td><textarea name="fieldDescription" cols="20" rows="4" id="fieldDescription"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Attach Your File</th>
      <td><input name="attachment" type="file"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: You have the file's type and size stored in their own variables already. What is the issue?

Comment: not quite sure on how to limit the attachment to only jpg, png, or gif and keep it under 5 megs.

Comment: Have you considered reading [the documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`if()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) statement to run comparisons on the file's `type` and `size` elements to limit them to the accepted values.

```
if ($fileType == "image/gif" || $fileType == "image/jpeg" || $fileType == "image/png") {
    // it's the right filetype
}

if ($_FILES['attachment']['size'] <= 5000000) {
    // it's the right file size
}
```

---

While outside the scope of your original question, these are **very** basic concepts. You *need* to read [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) and actually *understand* what's going on. Otherwise, you will eventually be copy/pasting something from the internet that you definitely don't want into your code.

Read some tutorials on PHP and file uploading, and once you understand fully, continue from there.

Comment: Thanks, definitely appreciated. Still very new to php in general. Trying to learn as much as I can and while I did understand the documentation I had trouble putting it into practice.